# Regex in Python 2.7 for extraction of information from Snort log files

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, snort

I'm trying to extract information from a [Snort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snort_%28software%29) file using regular expressions. I've sucessfully got the IP's and SID, but I seem to be having trouble with extracting a specific part of the text.

How can I extract part of a Snort log file? The part I'm trying to extract can look like `[Classification: example-of-attack]` or `[Classification: Example of Attack]`. However, the first example may have any number of hyphens and whilst the second instance doesn't have any hyphens but contains some capital letters.

How could I extract just `example-of-attack` or `Example-of-Attack`?

I unfortunately only know how to search for static words such as:

```
test = re.search("exact-name", line)
t = test.group()
print t
```

I've tried many different commands on the web, but I just don't seem to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
>>> m = re.search(r'\[Classification:\s*([^]]+)\]', line).group(1)
```

( [*Explanation*](http://liveforfaith.com/re/explain.pl?re=%5C%5BClassification%3A%5Cs*%28%5B%5E%5D%5D%2B%29%5C%5D&.submit=Explain%21&mode=SO&.cgifields=mode) | [Working Demo](https://eval.in/172775) )

Comment: Amazingly quick answer, works perfectly. Thanks for the explanation and demo links!

Answer (score 0):

You could use look-behinds,

```
>>> s = "[Classification: example-of-attack]"
>>> m = re.search(r'(?<=Classification: )[^\]]*', s)
>>> m
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7ff54a954370>
>>> m.group()
'example-of-attack'
>>> s = "[Classification: Example of Attack]"
>>> m = re.search(r'(?<=Classification: )[^\]]*', s).group()
>>> m
'Example of Attack'
```

Use regex module if there are more than one spaces after the string `Classification:`,

```
>>> import regex
>>> s = "[Classification:    Example of Attack]"
>>> regex.search(r'(?<=Classification:\s+\b)[^\]]*', s).group()
'Example of Attack
```

'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match any substring with the pattern `[Word: Value]`, you could use the following regex,

```
ptrn = r"\[\s*(\w+):\s*([\w\s-]+)\s*\]"
```

Here I've used two groups, one for the first word ("Classification" in your question) and one for the second (either "example-of-attack" or "Example of Attack").  It also requires opening and closing square brackets.  For example,

```
txt1 = '[Classification: example-of-attack]'
m = re.search( ptrn, txt1 )
>>> m.group(2)
'example-of-attack'
```